# ffmpeg Save incoming RTP audio only stream to file

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, sdp

I have setup kurento media server, which streams RTP audio (**only audio**). Now I am trying to test the received RTP stream. For that, I am saving the incoming RTP stream to file converting them to mp3. I am using the following command.

```
sudo ffmpeg -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -reorder_queue_size 100 -acodec opus -i mySdpOffer.sdp -acodec mp3 -y -f segment -segment_atclocktime 1 -segment_time 900 -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3
```

SDP offer:

```
v=0
t=0 0
m=audio 8978 RTP/AVP 98
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=recvonly
a=rtpmap:98 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:98 stereo=0; sprop-stereo=0; useinbandfec=1
```

I am getting the output mp3 file, but when I play it in VLC, there is no audio and while I stream for approximately 1 minute, the mp3 output file shows time 7 min long audio.

There are no errors from ffmpeg. Am I missing something here?

**UPDATE**

Adding ffmpeg logs,

Initials logs, before it starts capturing/decoding/writing to file

```
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-loglevel' ... matched as option 'loglevel' (set logging level) with argument 'debug'.
Reading option '-protocol_whitelist' ... matched as AVOption 'protocol_whitelist' with argument 'file,crypto,udp,rtp'.
Reading option '-reorder_queue_size' ... matched as AVOption 'reorder_queue_size' with argument '100'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'opus'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument '/home/ubuntu/Documents/inputAudio.sdp'.
Reading option '-acodec' ... matched as option 'acodec' (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument 'mp3'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-f' ... matched as option 'f' (force format) with argument 'segment'.
Reading option '-segment_atclocktime' ... matched as AVOption 'segment_atclocktime' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-segment_time' ... matched as AVOption 'segment_time' with argument '900'.
Reading option '-reset_timestamps' ... matched as AVOption 'reset_timestamps' with argument '1'.
Reading option '-strftime' ... matched as AVOption 'strftime' with argument '1'.
Reading option 'out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option loglevel (set logging level) with argument debug.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url /home/ubuntu/Documents/inputAudio.sdp.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument opus.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: /home/ubuntu/Documents/inputAudio.sdp.
[NULL @ 0x55e09081d440] Opening '/home/ubuntu/Documents/inputAudio.sdp' for reading
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] Format sdp probed with size=2048 and score=50
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] audio codec set to: opus
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] audio samplerate set to: 48000
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] audio channels set to: 2
[udp @ 0x55e090825200] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[udp @ 0x55e090824ec0] end receive buffer size reported is 131072
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] setting jitter buffer size to 100
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 141 bytes read:141 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] All info found
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 141 bytes read:141 seeks:0 frames:1
Input #0, sdp, from '/home/ubuntu/Documents/inputAudio.sdp':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/48000: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3.
Applying option acodec (force audio codec ('copy' to copy stream)) with argument mp3.
Applying option f (force format) with argument segment.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3.
Matched encoder 'libmp3lame' for codec 'mp3'.
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
detected 2 logical cores
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55e0908a2240] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/48000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55e0908a2240] Setting 'sample_rate' to value '48000'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55e0908a2240] Setting 'sample_fmt' to value 'fltp'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55e0908a2240] Setting 'channel_layout' to value '0x3'
[graph_0_in_0_0 @ 0x55e0908a2240] tb:1/48000 samplefmt:fltp samplerate:48000 chlayout:0x3
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x55e0908875c0] Setting 'sample_fmts' to value 's32p|fltp|s16p'
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x55e0908875c0] Setting 'sample_rates' to value '44100|48000|32000|22050|24000|16000|11025|12000|8000'
[format_out_0_0 @ 0x55e0908875c0] Setting 'channel_layouts' to value '0x4|0x3'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55e0908a1400] query_formats: 4 queried, 9 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] Selected stream id:0 type:audio
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] Opening 'out-20191105T1707.mp3' for writing
[file @ 0x55e0908a2bc0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Output #0, segment, to 'out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/48000: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1105
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libmp3lame
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
    Last message repeated 3 times
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] segment:'out-20191105T1707.mp3' starts with packet stream:0 pts:0 pts_time:0 frame:0
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0 -> pts:0 pts_time:0 dts:0 dts_time:0
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:1152 pts_time:0.024 dts:1152 dts_time:0.024 -> pts:1152 pts_time:0.024 dts:1152 dts_time:0.024
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:179904 pts_time:3.748 dts:179904 dts_time:3.748 -> pts:179904 pts_time:3.748 dts:179904 dts_time:3.748
[segment @ 0x55e09081f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:181056 pts_time:3.772 dts:181056 dts_time:3.772 -> pts:181056 pts_time:3.772 dts:181056 dts_time:3.772
```

last few lines.

```
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137124480 pts_time:2856.76 dts:137124480 dts_time:2856.76 -> pts:137124480 pts_time:2856.76 dts:137124480 dts_time:2856.76
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137130912 pts_time:2856.89 dts:137130912 dts_time:2856.89 -> pts:137130912 pts_time:2856.89 dts:137130912 dts_time:2856.89
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137132064 pts_time:2856.92 dts:137132064 dts_time:2856.92 -> pts:137132064 pts_time:2856.92 dts:137132064 dts_time:2856.92
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137133216 pts_time:2856.94 dts:137133216 dts_time:2856.94 -> pts:137133216 pts_time:2856.94 dts:137133216 dts_time:2856.94
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137134368 pts_time:2856.97 dts:137134368 dts_time:2856.97 -> pts:137134368 pts_time:2856.97 dts:137134368 dts_time:2856.97
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137135520 pts_time:2856.99 dts:137135520 dts_time:2856.99 -> pts:137135520 pts_time:2856.99 dts:137135520 dts_time:2856.99
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137136672 pts_time:2857.01 dts:137136672 dts_time:2857.01 -> pts:137136672 pts_time:2857.01 dts:137136672 dts_time:2857.01
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137137824 pts_time:2857.04 dts:137137824 dts_time:2857.04 -> pts:137137824 pts_time:2857.04 dts:137137824 dts_time:2857.04
[libmp3lame @ 0x5613ffd81900] Trying to remove 47 more samples than there are in the queue
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] stream:0 start_pts_time:0 pts:137138976 pts_time:2857.06 dts:137138976 dts_time:2857.06 -> pts:137138976 pts_time:2857.06 dts:137138976 dts_time:2857.06
[segment @ 0x5613ffd7f7c0] segment:'out-20191105T1651.mp3' count:0 ended
[AVIOContext @ 0x5613ffe02a00] Statistics: 1 seeks, 24 writeouts
size=N/A time=00:47:37.06 bitrate=N/A speed= 236x    
video:0kB audio:5803kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (/home/ubuntu/Documents/bz-squawk-sdpoffer/inputAudio.sdp):
  Input stream #0:0 (audio): 18568 packets read (2970880 bytes); 18568 frames decoded (17825280 samples); 
  Total: 18568 packets (2970880 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (out-%Y%m%dT%H%M.mp3):
  Output stream #0:0 (audio): 15473 frames encoded (17824896 samples); 15474 packets muxed (5942016 bytes); 
  Total: 15474 packets (5942016 bytes) muxed
18568 frames successfully decoded, 0 decoding errors
[AVIOContext @ 0x5613ffd86000] Statistics: 141 bytes read, 0 seeks
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: Post the ffmpeg log.

Comment: @szatmary, added last few logs. As you can see there are no errors in decoding or packet loss. You need the beginning logs as well. (There are lot of stream logs)

Comment: Added initial logs as well

Answer (score 1):

Check the kurento media server is sending Mono or Stereo audio data using the wireshark.

The SDP offer

```
a=rtpmap:98 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:98 stereo=0; sprop-stereo=0; useinbandfec=1
```

As per rfc 7587 : is suppose to recv mono data of opus codec.

ffmpeg logs :

```
Opus setting 
[sdp @ 0x55e09081d440] audio channels set to: 2

mp3 setting 
encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
Stream #0:0, 0, 1/48000: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, delay 1105
```

As per ffmpeg data it is stereo data received and trans-coded.

Comment: Probably, I am cutting off the stream by hitting ctrl+c.